# cannot trigger click on prime ng time calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, cypress, primeng

I have an angular application with a prime ng calendar.
Below is my sample code:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="myDate" [inline]="true" [timeOnly]="true"></p-calendar>
```

And this is the modified stackblitz starting from the prime ng one:

[stackblitz](https://primeng-calendar-demo-lrbgb4.stackblitz.io)

For test purposes, I would like to programmatically change the time by forcing clicks on chevron up/down icons, e.g. with cypress commands:

```
cy.get('.pi-chevron-up').first().click();
```

Unfortunately I can't achieve a trigger neither with jquery functions (see stackblitz attached).

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works ok for me, here's my test

```js
it('increments the counter via chevron click', () => {

  cy.visit('http://localhost:4200')

  let initial, next;

  cy.get('.pi-chevron-up')
    .first()
    .parent()
    .next('span')
    .then($el => initial = +$el.text())

  cy.wrap([1,2,3]).each(() => {   // do it 3 times

    cy.get('.pi-chevron-up')
      .first()
      .click()

    cy.get('.pi-chevron-up')
      .first()
      .parent()
      .next('span')
      .then($el => next = +$el.text())
      .then(() => {
        expect(next).to.eq(initial + 1)
        initial = next
      })
  })

})
```